# Calling a Class from a parent Theme issue Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress parent theme that my child theme is extending a lot of functionality from. My issue though is that when I want to use or extend a class from the Parent them in my child theme folder structure, I get errors of "class is not defined" or "class not found"

What is the correct way to use classes from the parent theme?

Here is an example of one of the classes:

```
class MyNewClass extends ReadAndDigestWidget {}
```

And that class will call more classes inside it that are from the parent theme.

Any help in understanding Wordpress and php more deeply is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

PHP is not an OOP language by design so the results can be trivial at times. Here is a basic example of how inheritance works in PHP

```
class ChildTheme extends ParentTheme {
       function parentDropDownMenu(){
           parent::dropDownMenu();
           //do additionall stuff
       }
    }

theme = new ParentTheme();
$theme->dropDownMenu();  // will call the parent function directly
$theme->parentDropDownMenu();     // will call the function override
```

Typically I wouldn't even override my parent's class methods in PHP but merely extend the class if I don't have complete control over the parent class. What if an upgrade takes place in wordpress and you override a must needed upgrade?

Comment: I understand how inheritance works. My struggle is extending or using parent theme classes. I want to create a new class in the child theme that is extended using a class that is included in the parent theme. However when I do this, and initialize it in functions.php of the child theme. I get an error saying that the new class I created cannot find the parent class that I'm extending it with. Does that make sense? How do you use classes in a child theme from a parent theme because as I understand it, the parent them is initialized second after the child theme?